# Unable to store a value outside of a URLSession thread

Tags: swift

I am trying to store a String taken from a parsed JSON file in a URLSession in order to change label text in the main body of the function, but the value is not stored.

When I try to print the value, it prints, but when I try to access it, it is an empty string. I tried to change the label text in the thread, but that is not allowed.

Here is the code:

My local function variable

```
        var jName = ""
```

The code that doesn't work

```
 guard let url = URL(string: "URLPLACEHOLDER") else { return }

        let session = URLSession.shared

        session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }
            guard let data = data else { return }


            let res = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Jobs].self, from:data)

            if let v = res.first?.jobName { 
                print(v)
                jName = v
            }



            }.resume()

        self.currentPerson.text = jName + " is currently walking."
```

As mentioned, v prints fine (it should have the value "BOB") but when I assign it to jName and try to change the label, only `" is currently walking."` shows up on the label.

Comment: You are missing the concept of asynchrone. Instead of `print(v)`, do `print("Inside the closure \(v)")`, and when do you `self.currentPerson.text = jName +...`, do `print("after the closure")`, the order of prints is not the one you think of. Look for "Swift + Async + Closure" to know how to deal with that.

Comment: Thank you for your response! 

I wouldn't like to print twice, I just want to change the label to `res.first?.jobName` -

Comment: It's not about "printing it twice", it's about understanding the asynchrone mecanism. It's a basic and important one. If you do as I say, you'll see why `jName` is empty after the closure.

Comment: ok i will look into it, thank you

Comment: The quick answer is doing `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.currentPerson.text = jName + " is currently walking."}` just after `jName = v`, but that's helpful just here, when you'll see the issue on another piece of code (because it's a common issue), it's better to understand what's going on.